# non-IDE C development environment

Tags: c, linux, command-line

How do I set up a non-IDE-based C development environment on Linux?

Comment: I think Frank is asking for instructions on how to set up an environment, not opinions on which one is the best.

Comment: @GoalBased:  I added a comment to my answer addressing set up.  However, the emacs or vi/gcc/make type of environment usually doesn't require set up on Linux, as it's already in place when Linux is installed.

Answer (score 13):

gcc + make + vi and you will live happily ever after!

Comment: Make is the worst build system, except for all the other ones.

Comment: Omg I couldn't agree more. Make is awful, but it's so much better than everything else. Same goes with gdb on Linux.

Comment: where are you all EMACS junkies? the boy is being baptized (VI).

Answer (score 8):

A pretty good development environment is most likely already there--no setup necessary.  This is because most Linux installations are [GNU/Linux](http://www.gnu.org/).  GNU provides all the pieces you need for C software development.

Use the 'which' command to make sure these programs are in your execution path

```
which gcc
which make
```

[Gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is your compiler.  [Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) lets you define the compiling and linking steps.  (It can call gcc for you.)

You are likely to have several editors installed such as vi, nano, and GNU [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).  To see if you have emacs (for instance), type

```
which emacs
```

If the `which` command returns a valid path (i.e. it doesn't say `which: no emacs in` ...) then that means you can run the program just by typing its name:

```
emacs
```

for example.

Comment: I believe on Ubuntu you need to `apt-get install build-essential`. On Arch, it's `pacman -S base-devel`. Not sure about other distros.

Comment: Appreciate that Brendan; I think that's the type of information he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, someone's gotta say it: Emacs, gcc, and make.

If - as a commenter suggested - you're looking for instructions on setting this up, there's probably no set up needed, as most Linux distributions I've used come with these programs already installed.

Comment: This is why I can't sleep at night.

Comment: If someone can't sleep at night because some other person somewhere might be using emacs, then the first person really needs to learn to appreciate how good they've got it and to live and let live ...

Comment: -1 for Emacs...  Only kidding.  It has been said that Emacs is an excellent operating system, all it needs is a decent text editor.  Fortunately, you can now get a vi emulator for it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay my environment:

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) or [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/), [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), GCC. If I have to code on the command line I'd probably go with vi or nano over emacs, I just can't cope with emacs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a masochist:

gcc + cmake + nano ;)

Make sure to edit your .nanorc file (you can copy an example from /etc/nanorc generally)

Comment: @Matt Joiner, not as bad as make :D

Answer (score 1):

Emacs + Cedet is the best

Answer (score 1):

I use gtkemacs, gcc, make but more often scons these days.

This question is dangerously close to inciting religious wars.  Let me get it started: All configurations other than mine are inferior.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend gcc + vim/vi + (make).

Vim/vi is almost impossible to "just pick up and use" because it will be completely foreign and you will struggle to even move the cursor or insert text, but fortunately, Vim comes with an extremely helpful tutor you can start by invoking the command *vimtutor* in the shell. It will get you up and running in no time!

While Vim's interface is really bizarre and esoteric at first, once you get used to it (shouldn't take very long once you finish vimtutor), you will see your productivity when editing code increase **dramatically**!